# Renaming an opened Application

Tags: process, instance, renaming

I am playing a game where I open 6 six of the same game.  So when I look it up it says the name of the game 6 times. I am doing this because I am multiboxing in a MMO.

I want to send instructions to a specific one of those 6 windows. Let me explain:

Window 1 is named "Everquest, Is an enchanter"  and I need this window to be named "EQenchanter1" so I can send this window specific commands. I have 6 of these windows and I want them to be unique and to not share the same process name.

Is it possible to rename a process like this?

thanks a lot for the Help so far....

I have come up with some coding so you maybe could figure it out

```
     on idle
      tell application "EQenchanter1"
     key code 91
      end tell
return 2

         tell application "EQenchanter2"
             key code 91       
           end tell
           return 2
   end idle
```

problem is that these two applications share the same name.. so first priority is to get the applications renamed.. Second is to make like a background keystroke send to those two windows.. so they will alternate instead of getting the same keystroke at the same time..

i dont know if you even can do this.. when i see people do key stroke they do

```
   tell application "Everquest" activate
      tell "System Events"
      keycode 91
      end tell
```

Comment: Is this programming related? What language/tools are you using?

Comment: I am using the applescript to make apps that do automatic hotkeys for me